# Finding the child element (anchor tag) within a table row

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find a child element within a table row. The code is in the below link. I am not able to get to find an anchor tag within a table row. What Am I doing wrong here?

http://jsfiddle.net/vXwNJ/2/

```
<a href="##" class="clickevent">Click Here</a>
<table>

<tr id="test_tr">
  <td>
      <a href="##" class="secondlink">Add New Row</a>
  </td>    
</tr>
<table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clickevent").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert($("#test_tr").find(".secondlink").tagName);
    });

});
```

Comment: With this little code, it's better to post directly in here. I went ahead and copy+pasted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$("#test_tr").find(".secondlink")[0]` to access the DOM element associated with the jQuery Object. Using `[1]` would point to the 2nd matched DOM element, and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works. Also is it possible to have some thing like $("#test_tr").find(".secondlink").attr('onClick','alert("hello"); e.preventDefault();')

Comment: Better yet to do $("#test_tr").find(".secondlink").click(function(e) {alert("hello"); e.preventDefault();});

Answer (score 5):

You have to remember that there is a difference between *jQuery Element* objects and actual *Elements*.

```
alert($("#test_tr").find(".secondlink")[0].tagName);
```

Doing `[0]` works because jQuery is also an array of DOM Element objects, there is also [$.get](http://api.jquery/jQuery.get).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to implement "double-clicking on rows" behavior on my table, which then simply follows an anchors href that is embedded in one of the cells in each row.

```
$("#table_id tr").dblclick(function(e){
if(e.target.parentNode.rowIndex){
    window.location = $("#table_id tbody tr:eq("+(e.target.parentNode.rowIndex-1)+") a:last").attr(href);
}
});
```

Notice the "a:last" part, this will grab the last anchor element in the table row.  You can also make this "a:first" and grab the first anchor element in that table row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the "content" of the link, use `.html()`

http://jsfiddle.net/vXwNJ/8/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, .find() returns a list of elements, you need to get the first one.

`$("#test_tr").find(".secondlink")[0].tagName`